# Ckeditor cursor style

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I need to change the style of cursor to "pointer" when editor is on readonly mode I tried two solutions:

1. Changing text style

   ```
   CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.on( 'contentDom', function() {
   CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.editable().attachListener( 
   CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.editable(), 'mouseover', function( evt ) { 
     if ( evt.data.getTarget().is( 'p' ) )
   {evt.data.getTarget().setAttributes ( {'style':"cursor:pointer "} ) 
    ;}//cursor:pointer

    });
   CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.editable().attachListener( 
   CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.editable(), 'mouseout', function( evt ) { 
           if ( evt.data.getTarget().is( 'p' ) )
   {evt.data.getTarget().setAttributes ( {'style':"cursor:pointer"} ) ;}          
   });
   });
   ```
2. ```
   CKEDITOR.document.getDocumentElement().setStyle("cursor","pointer");
   ```

First one worked when cursor on the text.

Second one changed the cursor in all page except the Editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just found the answer

```
var node = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.document.getBody();
var parent = node.getParent();
parent.setStyle("cursor","pointer");
```